# Tracking variables in Java

Tags: java

I am studying for a course in Java and I have trouble with the following question:

Let the classes A and B be

```
class A{
    int g;
    B b;

    A (B b){
        this.g = b.g-2;
        this.b = b;
    }

    void substract(){
        g -= 1;
    }
}

class B{
    int g;
    A a;

    B (int g){
        this.g = g;
        this.a = null;
    }

    void add(){
        g += 1;
    }
}
```

Now we have the following statements/declarations

```
B b = new B(6);
A a1 = new A(b);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);

void println(A x, B y){
    out.printf("%d - %d - %d\n", x.g, x.b.g, y.g);
}

void doSomething(){
    println(a1,b);
    a1.substract();
    println(a1, a1.b);
    A a2 = new A(a1.b);
    println(a2, b);
    b.a = a2;
    println(b.a, a1.b);
}
```

And now the question is what will be printed when doSomething() is called.

My approach for this is to track all the involved variables and see how they change. So I start with the first two statemens:

```
B b = new(B6);
    b.g = 6
    b.a = null.

A a1 = new A(b);
    a1.g = b.g-2 = 4
    a1.b = b --> a1.b.g = 6; a1.b.a = null
```

Then the first println becomes

```
println(a1,b) = 4 - 6 - 6
```

which is correct.

Then the line `a1.substract();` changes the variables of `a1` such that

```
    a1.g = 3
```

and the second println becomes

```
println(a1, a1.b) = 3 - 6 - 6,
```

which is correct.

Then `A a2 = new A(a1.b)` introduces a new type `A` such that

```
A a2 = new A(a1.b);
    a2.g = a1.b.g-2 = 4
    a2.b = b --> a2.b.g = 6; a2.b.a = null
```

then the next println becomes

```
println(a2,b) = 4 - 6 - 6
```

which is correct.

Now `b.a = a2;`, which means

```
b.a.g = 4
b.a.b.g = 6
b.a.b.a = null
```

And also, importantly, to me this means that `b.a` is linked with `a2`, thus if any of the variables of `b.a` are changed so are the ones from `a2` and vice versa. I am not sure though, if this is correct.

```
println(b.a, a1.b) = 4 - 6 - 6
```

which is correct.

And now I get into trouble with the next two statements

```
a1.b.add();
```

to me would mean we add one to `a1.b.g`, hence now

```
a1.b.g = 6 + 1 = 7
```

and

```
a2.b.add();
```

to me would mean we add one to `a2.b.g`, which is linked to `b.a.b.g` and hence now

```
a2.b.g = 7
b.a.b.g = 7
```

and thus

```
println(b.a, a1.b) = 4 - 7 - 6
```

but the answer states `4 - 8 - 8`.

Where do I go wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And also, importantly, to me this means that b.a is linked with a2, thus if any of the variables of b.a are changed so are the ones from a2 and vice versa. I am not sure though, if this is correct.

It is.

What you forgot is that `a1` was created so that `a1.b` is the same object as `b` (and so is `a2.b`). So `a1.b.add()` and `a2.b.add();` are the same as `b.add();`